# JavaScript save blob to localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, html, blob, web-storage

I am trying to save `blob` data (favicon) retrieved via AJAX, to `localStorage`.

**Code :**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 
'http://g.etfv.co/http://www.google.com',
true);
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function(e){ //Stringify blob...
    localStorage['icon'] = JSON.stringify(xhr.response);
    //reload the icon from storage
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = 
        function(e) {
            document.getElementById("myicon").src = fr.result;
        }
    fr.readAsDataURL(JSON.parse(localStorage['icon']));
    }
xhr.send(null);
```

The code is adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20724019/1433559) with minor modifications to make it work with `localStorage`.
localStorage saves all data as strings, so blobs need to be **stringified** somehow before being saved.

`JSON` doesn't deal with blobs as one of it's supported types, so it's no surprise that this code fails.

Is there any way to get the blob into localStorage?

Comment: Not sure, just a shot but if your request response was the binary itself, then you save it directly on localStorage..

Comment: Ah sorry, I was thinking of indexeddb, never mind.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113278/storing-image-data-for-offline-web-application-client-side-storage-database

Comment: @XGreen Yo man!. That is not a question, that's a doctoral thesis. Will check that out anyway.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just store the blob as a data uri in local storage

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 
'http://g.etfv.co/http://www.google.com',
true);
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function(e){ //Stringify blob...
    //reload the icon from storage
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = 
        function(e) {
            localStorage['icon'] = e.target.result;
            document.getElementById("myicon").src = localStorage['icon'];
        }
    fr.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
}
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: Well, at least this is inefficient. Try to compare `xhr.response.size()` with `e.target.result.length`. But I may resort to that in the end.

Comment: Its just over 33% larger (base64 encoding), but this is the only way I know of to convert the blob into a usable string. Maybe if you find a better way you can post it as an answer.

Comment: If I am going to store favicons they are going to be many, plus other data, so all the favicons can take 1mb from the available 5mb

Comment: You can compress: https://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html

Comment: Assuming the original favicon was e.g. PNG file, it's not going to compress anymore.

Answer (score 0):

We can now use the modern `fetch` API to do the job.

```js
const getFromCacheOrDownload = async (url) => {
    const base64CachedImg = localStorage.getItem(url)
    if (base64CachedImg) {
        const response = await fetch(base64CachedImg)
        const blob = await response.blob()
        return URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    } else {
        const response = await fetch(url)
        if (response.status === 429) {
            console.log('too many requests')
        }
        const blob = await response.blob()
        const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        const base64String = (await convertBlobToBase64(blob))
        localStorage.setItem(url, base64String)
        return imageUrl
    }
}
```

The above code will try to get the picture from the cache. If not, it downloads it and store it in the cache.

Comment: At this stage we might just as well be using Cache storage instead of localStorage as well...