# Downloading zipfile causes file corruption

Tags: javascript, zip

I tried to download a zipfile from a webserver programatically using javascript- and am facing challenges with the archive getting corrupted.

I am using the following function to download

```
function download(){
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open("GET", 'http://jadonchemicals.com/sample.zip');
        http.setRequestHeader("dataType", "jsonp");
        http.onreadystatechange = function () {
             if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) 
             {
              var blobdata=new Blob([http.responseText], {type:  "application/zip"});
             var a = document.createElement("a");
             a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobdata);
             a.click();
             }
         };
            http.send();
}
```

I get the following errors when I try to open the archive

```
a) The file header is corrupt
b) unexpected end of archive
```

As an example, while downloading the sample.zip file on this link, the file does get downloaded to a size of 975k.
http://jadonchemicals.com/Blobtozip/

When I try to do the same programatically using javascript by linking the script to a button, the file size increases to 1779k and the file is corrupted

I suspect this is a result of an encoding issue. Could you suggest what I should do to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

You can download a file in javascript like this:

```
<iframe id="my_iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<script>
function Download(url) {
    document.getElementById('my_iframe').src = url;
};
Download("http://jadonchemicals.com/sample.zip")
</script>
```

You just need to insert the code into your html document.
I have tried downloading your specified file using this and it was the correct 975KB and was not corrupt.

Comment: thanks @0liveradam8... I missed mentioning a critical part of the need. We also need to send the file to a cloud server and hence looking to form the file in LocalStorage from the blob. if I download, I cannot do this automatically. Building the file is causing the corruption

Comment: Perhaps this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008732/javascript-save-blob-to-localstorage can help you save blob to localStorage.