# Return a blob from an observable

Tags: angular, observable, blob

This function is supposed to read a value from localStorage or get it from API and return a blob in both ways.

This is the service function:

```
      getAudioFile (text: string): Observable<Blob> {
        if (localStorage.getItem(text)) {
           return new Observable(() => {
             return new Blob([localStorage.getItem(text)], {type: 'audio/wav'});
           });
        }
        return this.http.post(this.cors + this.apiUrl, {}, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
              'Accept' : 'audio/wav',
            },
            params: {
              voice: 'en-US_AllisonV3Voice',
              text : text
            },
            responseType: 'blob'
          }).pipe(map(res => {
            res.text().then((strBlob => {
              localStorage.setItem(text, strBlob);
            }))
            return res;
         }),catchError(this.handleError))
      }
```

And this is my component function:

```
  toSpeech() {
    this.toSpeechService.getAudioFile(this.text).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)          // show nothing when blob is from localstorage
      const EL_audio = document.querySelector("audio");
      EL_audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(res);
      EL_audio.load();
    });
}
```

This code works fine when the date should be fetched from API but when is it  read from localstorage, `console.log(res)` shows nothing!

Comment: You might want to covert your blob data first to as a data uri in local storage, You might want to check this, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008732/javascript-save-blob-to-localstorage)

Comment: Tried it and no difference was made! @NoxinDVictus

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to serialize the blobOject before write it into the localstorage, and deserialize once read it from localstorage:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Serialize: (to string):
**JSON.stringify();**

Deserialize :
**JSON.parse();**

e.g: In your code:

```
.pipe(map(res => {
            res.text().then((mYBlob => {
               const strBlob:string = JSON.stringify( mYBlob );
               localStorage.setItem('text', strBlob);
            }))
 return res;
         }),catchError(this.handleError))
´´´
  if (localStorage.getItem(text)) {
           return new Observable(() => {

           const blobString= localStorage.getItem('text');
           const myBlob= JSON.parse( blobString );

             return new Blob([ myBlob ], {type: 'audio/wav'});
           });
        }
```

Comment: I defiantly should somehow decode blob in order to save it in localStorage, but `JSON.stringify( )` is not the trick!