# How to store image in mongolab

Tags: javascript, mlab

I have checked the document of mongolab rest API but it seems the API does not support this feature.

Is it possible to convert an image to base64 and store it as a string at mongolab and decode it to image to display on HTML?

Please give me a solution in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950465/how-to-get-image-bytes-string-base64-in-html5-jquery-javascript) teaches how to obtain a Base64 representation of an image.